# What is a formal synonym phrase for cutting lane barbarously?

Tags: phrase-request, synonyms

What is a formal synonym phrase for cutting lane barbarously?

I know it mean move to another lane, but what about we want to express its barbarously action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such a case, I would use the adverb "**rashly**" or "**aggressively**" to describe the cutting of lanes.

> The distracted driver changed lanes **rashly** without checking for traffic
>
> The driver changed lanes **aggressively** cutting across the path of a schoolbus

The difference between rashly and aggressively is the driver's attitude - a rash driver does not drive safely, does not check before cutting lanes. An aggressive driver - while also rash - has a bullying attitude.